# Is there any interface to call __libm_sse2_sincos under MSVC?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, sse, trigonometry

I'm currently working on an optimization of some C codes under MSVC, in which some sin() and cos() calculations are performed.

I use the SSE implementations like:

```
a = _mm_set_pd(cos(w),sin(w));
```

However, when I check disassembly codes later, I find that Microsoft compiler interpret cos(w) and sin(w) as follows:

```
call        __libm_sse2_cos 
...
call        __libm_sse2_sin
```

In which cos and sin are called separately. But I would expect that compiler call __libm_sse2_sincos to calculate sin and cos with the same radian simultaneously.

So is it possible that I tell compiler to do this? or any interface to call them under MSVC? How about under Linux?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
double s, c;

sincos(w, &s, &c);
a = _mm_set_pd(c, s);
```

?

Comment: I guess sincos() is a function that GNU has, and I'm currently working with MSVC, and that's why I ask this question. However thanks for trying help.

Comment: OK - you asked about Linux too in your question, and `sincos` is standard in Linux (and most other non-Microsoft operating systems too).

Comment: OK - thx for the Linux part :) So let's move on to MSVC now, I actually tried codes like `call __libm_sse2_sincos` as ASM under MSVC, only got the error "Undefined label: __libm_sse2_sincos"

Comment: If MSVC doesn't have `sincos` then you either need to implement your own or maybe just write a wrapper around `sin` and `cos`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want sincos under MSVC, you can use the implementation(s) from the XNA math library, namely `XMVectorSinCos` and `XMScalarSinCos`, which suck as they are `float` only or you need to use an external library like AMD's [LibM](http://developer.amd.com/libraries/LibM/Pages/default.aspx) (for x64 only) or a smaller time one like [this](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/).